# Regarding how to use external libraries in eclipse (java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a complete beginner in Java using eclipse and even after installing those **correctly** external libraries,(I installed them in to my build path and they come in my referenced library section) which would make my job easy I can't use them for some reason.

```
import acm.*;
```

I used this to import all the classes of this library and when I tried to use those classes in my program, It didn't work for some reason.It gives me the following error if I try to use the method print() which is a method of the class IOconsole of this library.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method print(String) is undefined for the type ShortPrint

at ShortPrint.main(ShortPrint.java:5)
```

I don't know if I missed any steps but I'm pretty sure I have installed the libraries correctly,Just can't get them to use.

EDIT 1: Heres my program.

```
   import acm.*;

public class ShortPrint {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        print ("hello");

   }
}
```

Comment: `...which is a function...` One note about that quote, Java has no functions, only methods. This may be leading to some of your confusion. In the case that `print` is a static method, you can treat it as function like Everton below, else you need an instance of the `IOConsole` class in order to call the `print` method on, like Attila below.

Comment: I'm so sorry I know java has methods not functions.It just spit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an object of ShortPrint, like so

```
ShortPrnt sp = new ShortPrint();
sp.print("Hello");
```

I am guessing you are trying to call `print` like this:

```
ShortPrint.print("Hello");
```

which would only work is `print` was a static function of `ShortPrint`

Another possibility is that you do not inherit `ShortPrint` from `IOConsole`, this the `IOConsole.print` is not accessible from `ShortPrint`

UPDATE: after OP added code on usage, the suggestion is to add the import

```
import acm.io.*;
```

as the `IOConsole` class resides in the `acm.io` package.  Then change the call to

```
IOConsole cons = new IOConsole();
cons.print("hello");
```

as `print()` is not a static member of `IOConsole`

Comment: Yes, I think the same Attiia I think the inheritance thing is right.

Comment: I'll just edit and repost my PROGRAM you can check and tell me how to inherit.

Comment: try `IOConsole.print("hello");`

Comment: Nope Still didn't work, It says "IOConsole cannot be resolved"

Comment: OK, I just checked the [documentation](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/complete/acm/io/IOConsole.html): `IOConsole` is in the `acm.io` package.  Add `import acm.io.*;` as well, it should work now

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but that still gives the error I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You need to create an IOConsole object: `IOConsole cons - new IOConsole();` and call print on that: `cons.print("hello");`

Comment: It'll have to be `IOConsole io = new IOConsole();` and then `io.print("hello");`

Comment: Also I just discovered when I used the way you told me in the beginning it says that it cannot make a static reference to a nonstatic method print which means it's non static.

Comment: You see: use your own logic and the compiler error messages to find the right way :)  I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your import to:

```
import static acm.IOConsole.*
```

Since it appears that the `print()` method is `static` in `IOConsole`.

Comment: What happens when you type `import static acm.` and hits `Ctrl + spacebar`?

Comment: I may have messed up my example, try to import as I specified im my edit.

Comment: By the way on hitting ctrl+spacebar It says no default proposals.

Comment: So, the method isn't static. Go with @Attila